# how to pass different command line arguments to diffrent replicas in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml

i have multiple replicas of the same image, but i want to pass a different command line argument to each replica, in other words i want something similar to the following:

```
version: "3.3"
services:
      mycontainer:
        build: .
        image: MyImage
        deploy:
          replicas: 3
        command:
          - arg1 arg2 //container1 args 
          - arg3 arg4 //container2 args
          - arg4 arg5 //container3 args
```

but this does not work, all lines would be arguments for the first container. how do i solve this?

ps: MyImage has an entrypoint which is a shell scripts and i need to pass command lines to it

Answer (score 0):

No similar for-loop in docker-compose currently, but the latest version of docker-compose does support new yaml feature, [archor](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html), which can save the type, no need repeat some parts.

NOTES: if you want to increase the replicas, you have to add more services.

```
version: "3.9"

services:
    mycontainer1: &base
      build: .
      image: MyImage
      command:
        - arg1 arg2 //container1 args

    mycontainer2:
      <<: *base
      command:
        - arg3 arg4 //container2 args

    mycontainer3:
      <<: *base
      command:
        - arg5 arg6 //container3 args
```

Comment: how is this answer different from simply using more services? i want the same service with multiple replicas

Comment: The difference is, you can type less, don't need repeat some codes. 

you can't insist, when the feature is not supported at the moment in Docker-compose, mate. You need a workaround, or just repeat the codes by multiple services.